# Deezer web player broken with Google Chrome 46.0.x (ready event not firing)

Tags: google-chrome, deezer

I've just updated to the latest Google Chrome dev channel (46.0.2467.2 dev 64-bit) on OS X 10.10.4 and discovered the Deezer player no longer works either on the main deezer.com site, their API docs or my test app that uses the API

It seems the player ready event is not longer firing.
Any workarounds or is it a case of waiting for Deezer to update their player code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the current Chrome dev build has issues, the latest Canary build: 46.0.2470.0 canary (64-bit) is fine again!